# mysql returning more than one row

Tags: mysql

I have a mysql query that needs to return the supplier ID from the supplier table by searching with the supplier name but it keeps returning multiple values.

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`%` PROCEDURE `sp_insert_sup_order`(
supname varchar(50),
dat date,
total decimal(10,2)
)
BEGIN
insert into Supplier_Order
(
Supplier_ID,
SupDate,
Total,
Sup_Name
)
values
(
(select Supplier_ID from Supplier Where Supplier_ID.SupName =  supname ),
dat,
total,
supname
);
```

Thats the query. Any help with this will be appreciated thanks

Comment: Change this line: `(select Supplier_ID from Supplier Where Supplier_ID.SupName =  supname )` to: `(select Supplier_ID from Supplier Where Supplier.SupName = supname )`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
(select Supplier_ID from Supplier Where Supplier_ID.SupName =  supname )
```

this should be like this:

```
(select Supplier_ID from Supplier Where Supplier.SupName =  supname ),
```

And why do you store the supplier name and the id in the order ? that should not be done, image you have to change the name of the supplier, you will have to update all orders. Only the supplier id should be stored in the order table!

Comment: the name is stored there as we are able to delete suppliers and if we where to remove a supplier then we would not be able to find the order again

Comment: thank you so much that worked :) i sat the entire day with that problem

Comment: @prahielbhoodram one way to solve this is to just mark suppliers as deleted. so you don't have to show them, and can still get the name...